# C#, after get value from textarea, how to split 2 strings and store in 2 separate arrays?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ok I got the result in client textarea depend on user choose how many ip addresses they want like this,

```
Please add the following DNS entries
165.216.237.48   name.domain 
165.216.237.250   name.domain
```

The number of entries can vary, it could list 1, 3, or 5 ip addresses with domain name. I want C# to get the ip address and `name.domain` in every new line then split and store in 2 separate arrays for ip and domain. The C# textarea code is `txt.Text`. The first line need to be ignored. Advice?

Comment: Homework? What about IPv6?

Comment: What have you tried? You explain what you want but not what you have done to get that.

Comment: What you have tried till now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var ips = new List<string>();
var domains = new List<string>();
foreach (var elements in txt.Text
    .Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Skip(1)
    .Select(line => line.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)))
{
    ips.Add(elements[0]);
    domains.Add(elements[1]);
}
ipsArray = ips.ToArray();
domainsArray = domains.ToArray();
```